# How to access/import oracle.security.jps.service in Java using maven/dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have code that uses JpsServiceLocator, CredentialStore and PasswordCredential. I am trying to import the following:

```
import oracle.security.jps.service.JpsServiceLocator;
import oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.CredentialStore;
import oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.PasswordCredential;
```

I searched online, and it provides the jar files. However because I am using Maven, I would like to do this, not by importing the jar files, but by adding the correct dependency. I searched for the dependencies but they did not show. Do the dependency/dependencies exist or is jar file the only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about Oracle Credential Store Framework, it is not available in maven central. Some proprietary libraries may not be available in maven central. In this case, if you are able download the jar file/s, you can put all the libraries in local directory of the project. You have add the dependency in maven like this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>Credential_Framework</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/extLib/someJar1.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: you are suggesting me to download the jar files and put them in the local directory of the project. Then why would I have to add it to the maven pom file as a dependency? the point of maven dependency is to avoid having to download jar files, so if I download the jar file, why do you suggest to to the other one? I'm new to maven btw

Comment: Yes, we also do this when it is not available in maven central.

Comment: my question is like....if I download the jar file and include it in my local folder, then I can just do the import and that would be enough right? I wouldn't even need to add the dependency , am I right? my understanding is that dependencies are an alternative to having to download jar files and put them in our folder.

Comment: No, even if you download the jar files, you have to add the dependencies as I suggested in maven pom.xml otherwise you will not able to access. Maven checks all the required dependencies for the particular project.